# How do you aim the headlights in a 2001 Saturn LS1?

Tags: maintenance, headlight, saturn

The body was repaired after a front-end accident, but the headlights seem to be pointed down too much, and the illuminate the road in front of the car, but not that far out.

There are two hex sockets (white circles below) that I can turn, but they don't seem to change the angle of the headlights.

I've seen a few references online that say there's a vertical and sometimes a horizontal adjustment screw, but I can't seem to find it.

[image: Headlight mount]

Answer (score 1):

Position your vehicle to aim your headlights against a wall so you can see where the headlights are pointing.

There or torx screws located above each headlight inside the engine compartment as well as the sides.  The torx size is a #15.

Turn the screws in and out to adjust each headlamp independently of the other until they are positioned properly.

Here is an image
[image]

Comment: Looking at the picture, where do you think the torx screws are located exactly?

Comment: I put a diagram in the response for you.  Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, that's actually the same image as the -1 answer below.  I don't think it's the Saturn LS1 headlight.  I posted a picture of the headlight assembly in my question, and you can see that there are no adjustment screws (unless they're hidden)

Answer (score -2):

There is always a couple of adjustment screws, and this link seems to describe it fairly throughly

[How do you properly aim headlights?](http://www.saturnfans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=160907)

Comment: Thanks, I saw that post, the pictures and examples don't match the this Saturn LS1.